# Inequality involving exponential functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to solve this exponential inequality
$$ \frac{4}{7}\sqrt{4 - 4 \cdot 7^{x}+7^{2x}} > 7^{2x-1}-4 \cdot 7^{x-1}+1 $$

My solution is $\mathbb{R}$, since $a=2$ and union of the two possible solutions is $\mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone confirm this or correct me? Thanks!

Comment: What is $a$? It does not appear anywhere...

Comment: Maybe you can substitute $t=7^x$... ?

Comment: I don't think it's correct. Try $x=\frac{1}{2}$ or $x=\frac{1}{3}$... or even $x=1$

Comment: For sure it does not hold in $\mathbb{R}$. For large $x>0$ the LHS behaves as  $7^x$ and the RHS behaves like $7^{2x}$. therefore, for large $x$, the RHS grows faster and the inequality does not hold.

Comment: I got $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup (\log_7 (3),\log_7 (5))$

Comment: @PierreCarre Hi, $a$ was my substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $7$ and rewrite the inequality $\;\frac{4}{7}\sqrt{4-4\cdot 7^{x}+7^{2x}} > 7^{2x-1}-4\cdot 7^{x-1}+1\;$ as 
$$4\cdot \sqrt{(7^x-2)^2} > (7^x-2)^2+3.$$
Set $\;t=|7^x-2|$ and solve the quadratic inequality $$4t>t^2+3.$$
We get $\;t\in(1,3)$ or $$1<|7^x-2|<3.$$ This gives $$-1<7^x<1\quad \text{or}\quad 3<7^x<5.$$ I think you can finish from this.

Answer (score 1):

Put $y=7^{x}$ and  note that $\sqrt {4-4y+y^{2}}=|2-y|$. Hence the inequality is $\frac 4 7 |2-y| >\frac 1 7 y^{2}-\frac 4 7 y+1$. This is certainly false for large values of $y$ , hence for large values of $x$. So your answer is not correct. Now try solving the inequality $4  |2-y| > y^{2}- 4 y+7$.

Comment: My first solution is $(-\infty,0)$ for $ y = ( - \infty ,2 )$ and $[2, \infty)$ for $y=[2,\infty)$. Is it correct?

Comment: @user376343 Sorry, there was a typo.